# Why are these query plans so different?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-rds

We have two RDS environments with read replicas (test has one, production has three) and a conundrum: why does the same query, over the same data (19.5million rows for the view) + same indexes, take close to 1600msec or more in the production environment compared to the test environment's sub-millisecond response?

Both environments are using the latest RDS PostgreSQL (11.8), are using the same VM type of db.m5.xlarge, and to the best of my ability to check, are configured the same - apart from the number of read replicas.

I don't know what to look at (or into) to figure out why the query plans are *so* different.

Edit: The settings in both test and production containing the word `parallel` are

```
 enable_parallel_append                          on     
 enable_parallel_hash                            on     
 force_parallel_mode                             off    
 max_parallel_maintenance_workers                2      
 max_parallel_workers                            8      
 max_parallel_workers_per_gather                 2      
 min_parallel_index_scan_size                    512kB  
 min_parallel_table_scan_size                    8MB    
 parallel_leader_participation                   on     
 parallel_setup_cost                             1000   
 parallel_tuple_cost                             0.1
```

The query plan for test is

```sql
db=> explain (analyze, buffers)
select columns
   from view
   where ( search_column like '342 KING ST C'||'%' ESCAPE '~' OR search_column like '342 KING STREET C' ||'%' ESCAPE '~' OR search_column like '342 KING SAINT C' ||'%' ESCAPE '~' )
   AND result_type in (1, 2, 3, 4)
     limit 10
;
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=18.24..97.45 rows=10 width=152) (actual time=0.034..0.095 rows=9 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=76
   ->  Append  (cost=18.24..44543.84 rows=5621 width=152) (actual time=0.033..0.093 rows=9 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=76
         ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=18.24..44464.47 rows=5449 width=151) (actual time=0.033..0.075 rows=9 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=55
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=18.24..44409.98 rows=5449 width=219) (actual time=0.032..0.073 rows=9 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=55
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _address_full_location a  (cost=17.80..21.82 rows=5449 width=110) (actual time=0.022..0.031 rows=9 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ((address_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (address_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (address_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
                           Filter: ((address_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (address_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (address_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
                           Heap Blocks: exact=7
                           Buffers: shared hit=19
                           ->  BitmapOr  (cost=17.80..17.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=0 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=12
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_full_location_ix_address_search_isunit  (cost=0.00..4.57 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((address_display >= '342 KING ST C'::text) AND (address_display < '342 KING ST D'::text))
                                       Buffers: shared hit=4
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_full_location_ix_address_search_isunit  (cost=0.00..4.57 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=9 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((address_display >= '342 KING STREET C'::text) AND (address_display < '342 KING STREET D'::text))
                                       Buffers: shared hit=4
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_full_location_ix_address_search_isunit  (cost=0.00..4.57 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((address_display >= '342 KING SAINT C'::text) AND (address_display < '342 KING SAINT D'::text))
                                       Buffers: shared hit=4
                     ->  Index Scan using _property_ix_property_id on _property p  (cost=0.43..8.14 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=9)
                           Index Cond: (a.property_id = property_id)
                           Buffers: shared hit=36
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _address_street_location st  (cost=13.43..17.45 rows=166 width=172) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((street_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (street_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (street_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
               Filter: ((street_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (street_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (street_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
               Buffers: shared hit=9
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=13.43..13.43 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=9
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_street_location_ix_street_search  (cost=0.00..4.43 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((street_display >= '342 KING ST C'::text) AND (street_display < '342 KING ST D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=3
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_street_location_ix_street_search  (cost=0.00..4.43 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((street_display >= '342 KING STREET C'::text) AND (street_display < '342 KING STREET D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=3
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_street_location_ix_street_search  (cost=0.00..4.43 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((street_display >= '342 KING SAINT C'::text) AND (street_display < '342 KING SAINT D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=3
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _address_suburb_location su  (cost=12.90..16.91 rows=5 width=158) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((suburb_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (suburb_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (suburb_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
               Filter: ((suburb_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (suburb_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (suburb_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
               Buffers: shared hit=6
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=12.90..12.90 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=6
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_suburb_location_ix_suburb_search  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((suburb_display >= '342 KING ST C'::text) AND (suburb_display < '342 KING ST D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=2
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_suburb_location_ix_suburb_search  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((suburb_display >= '342 KING STREET C'::text) AND (suburb_display < '342 KING STREET D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=2
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_suburb_location_ix_suburb_search  (cost=0.00..4.30 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((suburb_display >= '342 KING SAINT C'::text) AND (suburb_display < '342 KING SAINT D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=2
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on _address_postcode_location pc  (cost=12.88..16.90 rows=1 width=147) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((postcode_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (postcode_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (postcode_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
               Filter: ((postcode_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (postcode_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (postcode_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
               Buffers: shared hit=6
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=12.88..12.88 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=6
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_postcode_location_ix_postcode_search  (cost=0.00..4.29 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((postcode_display >= '342 KING ST C'::text) AND (postcode_display < '342 KING ST D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=2
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_postcode_location_ix_postcode_search  (cost=0.00..4.29 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((postcode_display >= '342 KING STREET C'::text) AND (postcode_display < '342 KING STREET D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=2
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on _address_postcode_location_ix_postcode_search  (cost=0.00..4.29 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((postcode_display >= '342 KING SAINT C'::text) AND (postcode_display < '342 KING SAINT D'::text))
                           Buffers: shared hit=2
 Planning Time: 3.427 ms
 Execution Time: 0.174 ms
(74 rows)
```

The production query plan is

```sql
db=> explain (analyze, buffers)
select columns
   from view
   where ( search_column like '342 KING ST C'||'%' ESCAPE '~' OR search_column like '342 KING STREET C' ||'%' ESCAPE '~' OR search_column like '342 KING SAINT C' ||'%' ESCAPE '~' )
   AND result_type in (1, 2, 3, 4)
     limit 10
;
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1000.00..2053.45 rows=10 width=151) (actual time=1243.140..1680.998 rows=9 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=15815 read=425564
   I/O Timings: read=835.908
   ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..603046.39 rows=5715 width=151) (actual time=1243.139..1682.255 rows=9 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=15815 read=425564
         I/O Timings: read=835.908
         ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..601474.89 rows=5614 width=151) (actual time=1329.613..1677.727 rows=3 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=15815 read=425564
               I/O Timings: read=835.908
               ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.43..581643.66 rows=5541 width=150) (actual time=1290.180..1638.292 rows=3 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared hit=328 read=425564
                     I/O Timings: read=835.908
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.43..581588.25 rows=2309 width=218) (actual time=1290.178..1638.288 rows=3 loops=3)
                           Buffers: shared hit=328 read=425564
                           I/O Timings: read=835.908
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _address_full_location a  (cost=0.00..562773.42 rows=2309 width=109) (actual time=1290.140..1638.218 rows=3 loops=3)
                                 Filter: ((address_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (address_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (address_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 6258793
                                 Buffers: shared hit=290 read=425564
                                 I/O Timings: read=835.908
                           ->  Index Scan using _property_ix_property_id on _property p  (cost=0.43..8.14 rows=1 width=5) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=9)
                                 Index Cond: (a.property_id = property_id)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=38
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _address_street_location st  (cost=0.00..19162.97 rows=70 width=172) (actual time=57.433..57.433 rows=0 loops=2)
                     Filter: ((street_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (street_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (street_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 280386
                     Buffers: shared hit=15074
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _address_suburb_location su  (cost=0.00..535.86 rows=3 width=158) (actual time=2.798..2.798 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((suburb_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (suburb_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (suburb_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 17472
                     Buffers: shared hit=356
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _address_postcode_location pc  (cost=0.00..104.33 rows=1 width=147) (actual time=0.629..0.629 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((postcode_display ~~ '342 KING ST C%'::text) OR (postcode_display ~~ '342 KING STREET C%'::text) OR (postcode_display ~~ '342 KING SAINT C%'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 4598
                     Buffers: shared hit=57
 Planning Time: 2.846 ms
 Execution Time: 1682.402 ms
(39 rows)
```

Comment: I haven't look at the whole of the above yet.  My first question though would be; have you run `ANALYZE` on the production  server yet or recently?

Comment: Yes, we do an `ANALYZE` that as part of our nightly procedures.

Comment: Well on  explain.depesz.com for [Test](https://explain.depesz.com/s/0xPp) and [Production](https://explain.depesz.com/s/t7DC) the big difference is the production is using parallel heavily. Are the parallel setting different for the two instances? Also what is the actual row count for `view` in each server?

Comment: That's a really useful site, thankyou! I'll add the other info in a question edit.

Comment: Not sure what is going on. Are the view definitions the same in each database?  You could do a once over on this [Parallel](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/parallel-query.html) to see if anything stands out.

Comment: Yup, the view definitions are the same. I'll have another look at the docs for Parallel too.

Comment: Maybe they have different collations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index can only be used to support a front-anchored LIKE query if the index collation is C, or the index is built with the text_pattern_ops operator (or similar).  It looks like one of those two things is true for test, but is not true for prod.

Comment: WOW. And indeed it is - test has lc_collate=C, prod has en_US.UTF.

Comment: We've rebuilt our RDS with lc_collate=C, and now the production environment is getting us sub-10msec for that query. Thankyou very much!